# How to turn off Eclipse console on Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration

So I change the `-vm` argument for `eclipse.exe` using the `eclipse.ini` settings file, and now there's an command prompt console (even if I remove the `-vm` value).

Does anyone know how to turn off the console so I only have the eclipse GUI and not the console window? I'm running MS Windows 7.

**EDIT: Solved thanks to [Kennet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908188/how-to-turn-off-eclipse-console-on-windows#2908462), the problem was I was using `java.exe` instead of `javaw.exe`!!!**

Comment: Maybe a screenshot would help?

Comment: I changed my -vm value, but nothing happened. What VM are you using? Are you sure you didn't do anything else? Could you upload a screenshot of the console you are referring to?

Comment: try this `eclipse.ini`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590

Comment: If Kennet answered correctly can you please accept his answer? Thanks

Answer (score 14):

```
eclipse.exe -vm <path-to-java>\javaw.exe
```

javaw is a 'no console version' of java

Comment: if you have several jdks installed you might have to provide a full path (to make sure). also these windows slashes: \ have to be escaped \\ or converted to unix slashes /

Comment: When you specify java(w).exe on the command line, java will be forked in a second process.  You can also specify "-vm path/jvm.dll" and then java will be loaded in-process using the JNI invocation API.

Comment: "The more you know". Thanks @Andrew!